# File don't show with "ls -a" but was detected by Malwarebytes

Tags: macos, terminal, imac, malware

On the terminal, I search for the file `com.pplauncher.plist` on the directory

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/
```

through the command `ls -a`, but such a file wasn't found. Later, I installed Malwarebytes and ran it. Then, it detected the file `com.pplauncher.plist` as a malware exactly in the same directory I was looking at.

My question is: why this has happened? I thought every file on my computer could be shown on the terminal.

PS: I was trying to delete this file because I found `mshelper` running on my iMac, which turns out to be a malware used to mine cryptocurrency.

Comment: Welcome on Ask ≠. •••• Your use of `ls` is correct and you are fully right: `ls -a` will show you all files whatever their hidden status for the Finder might be. •••• I suggest you to add the `-B` flag to your `ls` in case this file name contained some special characters to hide it (for example with a "\r" inside of a file-name, its printing in Terminal will hide the beginning of the name): •••• `ls -aB /Library/LaunchDaemons/`.

Comment: Thanks, @dan =) can you give me a reference where I can find a list of these special characters that can hide parts of a file-name?

Comment: You should try using Spotlight Search for this file or download a free app called EasyFind. https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11076/easyfind

Comment: Just do a `ls -aBl /Library/LaunchDaemons` and include the text output to your original question to check if my hypothesis is of any help.

Comment: Please tell us the full command that you ran.

Comment: If it the cool tab hijack you have then it's possible that it's been deleted or put in quarantine already.  Also check out https://macsecurity.net/view/402-coolnewtabtheme-virus-macos for other possible file names.  I've moved to BitDefender now as Amazon has a 5 computer family offer at less than BitDefender sell it for.  Caught two Windoze infections in old emails that Avast missed and virtually no impact on CPU.

Comment: Hello everyone. Unfortunately I cannot test any commands now because the file has been deleted by malwarebytes already. 
I can only talk about what exactly I've done.
First, I changed the working directory by typing
`cd /Library/LaunchDaemons/`
Then, I ran the command `ls -a`. A list with fewer than 10 files showed up, none of them containing `pplauncher.plist` in their names.

Comment: Just to be sure, @leticia run once more Malwarebytes and check your `mshelper` was removed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do the directory listing as root or with a sudo.  It is possible that the malware changed permissions on the plist file.

Comment: I think that is the most reasonable answer for what could've happened. Unfortunately, I cannot test it... but you're probably right! Thanks!

Comment: @leticia : however the plist mode could have been changed, any user in this directory should see it with `ls -aBl`.